# MapBox is crashing

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, mapbox-android

**Hi, i am using mapbox (Java) on android studio and want to get my user location and navigation working but i am having errors when i run the start navigation button and then crashes, please could you help as i have been stuck for 4 days now.**

**my MapActivity.java**

```
package com.example.a18004671_opsc7312_taskapp;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsListener;
import com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsManager;
import com.mapbox.api.directions.v5.models.DirectionsResponse;
import com.mapbox.api.directions.v5.models.DirectionsRoute;
import com.mapbox.geojson.Feature;
import com.mapbox.geojson.Point;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.geometry.LatLng;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.location.LocationComponent;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.location.modes.CameraMode;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.Style;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.layers.SymbolLayer;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.sources.GeoJsonSource;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.NavigationLauncher;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.NavigationLauncherOptions;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.route.NavigationMapRoute;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.v5.navigation.NavigationRoute;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

import static com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.layers.PropertyFactory.iconAllowOverlap;
import static com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.layers.PropertyFactory.iconIgnorePlacement;
import static com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.layers.PropertyFactory.iconImage;



public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        MapboxMap.OnMapClickListener, PermissionsListener {

    MapView mapView;
    MapboxMap mapboxMap;
    LocationComponent locationComponent;
    PermissionsManager permissionsManager;
    DirectionsRoute currentRoute;
    NavigationMapRoute navigationMapRoute;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Mapbox.getInstance(this, "pk.eyJ1IjoiY29zdGFuZGlubyIsImEiOiJja2F4c2E0aDAwNnp6MndwaWtvY3RnMXRmIn0.blAhMKMqI8ejvU-clCPYdQ");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);

    }


    public void startNavigationBtnClick(View v) {
        boolean simulateRoute = true;
        NavigationLauncherOptions options = NavigationLauncherOptions.builder()
                .directionsRoute(currentRoute)
                .shouldSimulateRoute(simulateRoute)
                .build();

        NavigationLauncher.startNavigation(MapActivity.this, options);

    }


    @Override
    public void onExplanationNeeded(List<String> permissionsToExplain) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPermissionResult(boolean granted) {
        if (granted) {
            enableLocationComponent(mapboxMap.getStyle());
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMapClick(@NonNull LatLng point) {

        Point destinationPoint = Point.fromLngLat(point.getLongitude(), point.getLatitude());
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.

        }
        Point originPoint = Point.fromLngLat(locationComponent.getLastKnownLocation().getLongitude(),
                locationComponent.getLastKnownLocation().getLatitude());


        GeoJsonSource source = mapboxMap.getStyle().getSourceAs("destination-source-id");

        if(source!=null)
        {
            source.setGeoJson(Feature.fromGeometry(destinationPoint));
        }

        getRoute(originPoint,destinationPoint);


        return true;
    }

    private void getRoute(Point originPoint, Point destinationPoint)
    {
        NavigationRoute.builder(this)
                .accessToken(Mapbox.getAccessToken())
                .origin(originPoint)
                .destination(destinationPoint)
                .build()
                .getRoute(new Callback<DirectionsResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<DirectionsResponse> call, Response<DirectionsResponse> response) {
                        if(response.body()!=null && response.body().routes().size()>1)
                        {
                            currentRoute = response.body().routes().get(0);

                            if(navigationMapRoute!=null)
                            {
                                navigationMapRoute.removeRoute();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                navigationMapRoute = new NavigationMapRoute(null,mapView,mapboxMap,R.style.NavigationMapRoute);

                            }


                            navigationMapRoute.addRoute(currentRoute);

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<DirectionsResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(@NonNull MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
        this.mapboxMap = mapboxMap;

        this.mapboxMap.setMinZoomPreference(12);
        mapboxMap.setStyle(getString(R.string.navigation_guidance_day), new Style.OnStyleLoaded() {
            @Override
            public void onStyleLoaded(@NonNull Style style) {
                enableLocationComponent(style);
                addDestinationIconLayer(style);
                mapboxMap.addOnMapClickListener(MapActivity.this);

            }
        });


    }

    private void addDestinationIconLayer(Style style)
    {
        style.addImage("destination-icon-id",
                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.mapbox_marker_icon_default));


        GeoJsonSource geoJsonSource = new GeoJsonSource("destination-source-id");
        style.addSource(geoJsonSource);

        SymbolLayer destinationSymbolLayer = new SymbolLayer("destination-symbol-layer-id","destination-source-id");
        destinationSymbolLayer.withProperties(iconImage("destination-icon-id"),iconAllowOverlap(true),
                iconIgnorePlacement(true));


        style.addLayer(destinationSymbolLayer);

    }

    private void enableLocationComponent(@NotNull Style loadedMapStyle) {
        if (PermissionsManager.areLocationPermissionsGranted(this)) {
            locationComponent = mapboxMap.getLocationComponent();
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


                return;
            }
            locationComponent.activateLocationComponent(this, loadedMapStyle);
            locationComponent.setLocationComponentEnabled(true);

            locationComponent.setCameraMode(CameraMode.TRACKING);

        }

        else
        {
            permissionsManager = new PermissionsManager(this);
            permissionsManager.requestLocationPermissions(this);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        permissionsManager.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode,permissions,grantResults);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mapView.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mapView.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
        mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }
}
```

**my XML layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.a18004671_opsc7312_taskapp.MapActivity">

    <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start Navigation"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:onClick="startNavigationBtnClick"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**and the ERRORS i am getting**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.a18004671_opsc7312_taskapp, PID: 414
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:402)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7357)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7334)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:808)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28200)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7478)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:549)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7357) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7334) 
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:808) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28200) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7478) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:549) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Null directionsRoute
        at com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.AutoValue_NavigationLauncherOptions$Builder.directionsRoute(AutoValue_NavigationLauncherOptions.java:168)
        at com.example.a18004671_opsc7312_taskapp.MapActivity.startNavigationBtnClick(MapActivity.java:75)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7357) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7334) 
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:808) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28200) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7478) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:549) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
```

Comment: It looks like the error is in `MapActivity.java` in line 75. It seems like `currentRoute` is `null` when the button is clicked. In line 142 you're setting it, but this might happen *after* the button is clicked. In `startNavigationBtnClick`, you could check if `currentRoute == null` and return from it before using `currentRoute`, that way the `null` will no longer be accessed

Answer (score 3):

The error message hints at the possibility that `currentRoute` has not been set when clicking the button.

This is why `directionsRoute(currentRoute)` throws a `NullPointerException`.

To fix this, you can check if `currentRoute` has been set before using it in `startNavigationBtnClick`.

An implementation of that could look like this:

```
public void startNavigationBtnClick(View v) {
    if (currentRoute == null) {
        return; // Route has not been set, so we ignore the button press
    }
    boolean simulateRoute = true;
    NavigationLauncherOptions options = NavigationLauncherOptions.builder()
            .directionsRoute(currentRoute)
            .shouldSimulateRoute(simulateRoute)
            .build();

    NavigationLauncher.startNavigation(MapActivity.this, options);
}
```

Comment: Thank You! i fixed it as well as deleted everything and pasted back in and it worked somehow.